# ReactJS: How to receive post request from an external application in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I am submitting  a request and that redirects to a external website for confirmation. After confirming, that external website is giving me some data to my react app's route as a ***POST request***. But my routes are receiving ***GET requests***. So, how can I receive a  ***POST request*** in ReactJS

Answer (score 1):

You can make ajax requests like this in react with axios package:

```
import axios from 'axios'


<button
onClick={()=>{
  // axios.get()
  axios.post("url" , { name : "name" }  ).then(res=>{
    console.log(res)
  })
}}
>Send Request</button>
```

Or you can use the fetch api :

```
<button
onClick={()=>{
  fetch("url",
{
    method: "POST", // GET
    body: JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 2})
})
.then(function(res){ console.log(res) })
.catch(function(res){ console.log(res) })
}}
>Send Request</button>
```